# How to customize chrome browser in cypress?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

I just learned web automation test using cypress. But when open cypress uses "yarn" and E2E testing configuration, there is no chrome browser option. My question is, how to add chrome browser in my cypress? Even though the chrome browser is already installed on my laptop. Hopefully someone can help. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a suggestion from Cypress [here] that may help:

> I believe that clearing the AppData may solve the problem. To do this:
>
> - open up the cypress app
> - Go to File -> View App Data
> - Delete everything in here
> - Close cypress and open it up again
>
> And it should recreate all the browser profiles + extension

If that does not work, the problem is probably with the chrome install itself, try uninstalling / reinstalling it.

You can also pick up [Chrome Dev](https://www.google.com/chrome/dev/), install it and  Cypress will show that as a separate option.